Usage of Additional/Custom config suggested values fields in External Applications
I've been told that we can restrict an external application LoanPayment link type to only appear on certain loan or share types by setting the first field of Additional/Custom config suggested values to linkEntitlementConfiguration and specify the share and loan types in the second field with this format shareLoanTypes:ShType01,shType02,LnType01,LnType02.
This appears to work for the external application we added those settings to, but I can't find any documentation regarding this.  The knowledge base says those fields are used internally for passing custom SSO data.
Does adding linkEntitlementConfiguration on external applications LoanPayment link types control which share or loan types it will appear on?
If so, is there a way to restrict the external application to only show on a specific external loan type?
I checked Banno documentation and opened a case.  Jack Henry support directed me to post my question here.

out of curiosity, which team at Jack Henry was the source of this part of the question? "I've been told that we can restrict an external application LoanPayment link type to only appear on certain loan or share types"

I did not get that directly from Jack Henry.  Another CU that is working on the same integration as we are did.

Jaime, I just realized we met at last year's CUBuild.  That was a blast.

Oh, cool! Agreed, it was fun. Looks like the registration for the 2024 edition is now open: https://www.cubuild.org


Does adding linkEntitlementConfiguration on external applications
LoanPayment link types control which share or loan types it will
appear on?
If so, is there a way to restrict the external application to only
show on a specific external loan type?

If you set the linkEntitlementConfiguration to shareLoanTypes only accounts with the LnType or ShType specified will be shown a link for the external application.
You'll have to specify all of the loan/share types you want to include.

What about External Loans?  Does LnType work for those as well or is it something like ExtLnType?

Is there a way to list External Loan Types?

For external loans used ExLnXX where XX is the external loan type. I'm not aware of a way to list all external loan types.
